# Swift, When assigning the same value type instance to two variables, do only variables corresponding to array types have the same memory address?

Tags: arrays, swift, optimization, memory, copy-on-write

I read in Swift value types use copy on write to optimization in [OptimizationTips](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/OptimizationTips.rst) docs

> All standard library containers in Swift are value types that use COW (copy-on-write) to perform copies instead of explicit copies. In many cases this allows the compiler to elide unnecessary copies by retaining the container instead of performing a deep copy.

To check it, I assigned [1,2,3] to `a` variable and assigned `a` to `b` again. And I printed each variable's memory address using custom function.
Finally I found their addresses are exactly same unless I chage value like `b.append(4)`

```swift
func address(of object: UnsafeRawPointer) -> String{
    let address = Int(bitPattern: object)
    return String(format: "%p", address)
}

//same memory address
var a = [1, 2, 3]
var b = a
address(of: &a) //0x600002b74c20
address(of: &b) //0x600002b74c20

b.append(2)
address(of: &a) //0x600002b74c20
address(of: &b) //0x600001d509d0
```

After this experiment, I tried same on dictionary, set and string. At this point I found something strange because each variable's memory address is different although I assigned same instance.

```swift
//string, dic, set
var c = "1b"
var d = c
address(of: &c) //0x10eaec670
address(of: &d) //0x10eaec680

var e = ["hi" : 3, "bye" : 3]
var f = e
address(of: &e) //0x10eaec690
address(of: &f) //0x10eaec698

var g: Set = [1, 2]
var h = g
address(of: &g) //0x10eaec6a0
address(of: &h) //0x10eaec6a8
```

Array is a type of collection, so I expected other collections also work the same way. But only Array variables have the same memory address. And I can't guess why.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prove "copy-on-write" on String type in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46747363/how-to-prove-copy-on-write-on-string-type-in-swift)

Comment: @FabioFelici You saved my day! Although the answer only covered `Array` and `String`, but now I can guess the way passing unsafePointer of `Dictionary` and `Set` is working like `String` (It makes their pointers different!). Thank you